# replace tags with PHP variables using preg_match

Tags: php, tags, replace

`{$thisname}` should be converted to `<?php echo $thisname; ?>`.

`{thisname}` should be converted to `<?php echo $thisname; ?>`.

`{$this.movie.games}` && `{$this.new}` should be converted respectively to `<?php echo $this["movie"]["games"]; ?>` and `<?php echo $this["new"]; ?>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$tpl = 'Name: {$name}, Surname: {surname}, City: {$person.address.city}';

function tpl2php($m){
    $var =  $m[1];
    if(strpos($var,'.')){
        $varArr = explode('.',$var);
        $var = $varArr[0];
        for($i=1;$i<count($varArr);$i++){
            $var .= '["' . $varArr[$i] .'"]';
        }
    }
    return '<?php echo $' . $var . '; ?>';
}

$php = preg_replace_callback('/{\$?([_a-z][\w\.]+[\w])}/iS','tpl2php',$tpl);
// Name: <?php echo $name; ?>, Surname: <?php echo $surname; ?>, City: <?php echo $person["address"]["city"]; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a templating system, I suggest using http://phpsavant.com/ although it looks like you're more interested in [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) or [Dwoo](http://dwoo.org/)

There's no need to re-invent the wheel :)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but adding a huge templating system just to be able to do this kind of replacement may not be what the user wants or needs. (On the other hand, on second thought, it may save the OP a ton of work, especially when it comes to parsing complex stuff like `var1.var2.var3` so +1)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [str_replace](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function.

Comment: That replaces all the } tags with ; ?> which i dont want to do...I wanted to use preg match

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace and [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) are more flexible than str_replace, especially if you have to parse a string like this.movie to $this["movie"]. It will not be an easy task though.