# Converting tags to PHP tags using PHP 

Tags: php, tags, replace

How can I change

```
{for ...cond.... }
somethinginbetween
{/for}
```

to

```
<?php for (...cond...){ ?>
somethinginbetween
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I replace certain tags with the content of PHP variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522535/how-do-i-replace-certain-tags-with-the-content-of-php-variables)

Comment: Is is specifically `for` tags, or could it any tag using that language

Comment: it could be using if, else if, elseif, foreach, while, do while, nothing else

Comment: what do you need that for? are you going to translate a smarty template into a php file? if so i'd actually do it by hand. you also could use the alternative versions of php tags like this: instead of `for(){....}` you write: `for(): .... endfor;` with that you can replace each {for cond} with <?php for(cond):?> and each /for with <?php endfor: ?> the same is applicable to if, foreach, switch ..... see here http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: I have a feeling that this could be achieved with two pregmatch statements in a loop, for example get each set of {for cond}{/for} then replace that to the php code and loop through all the items. However I am extremely poor skilled with regex and I need this code really now to be honesh. Thanks.

Comment: as long as "cond" doesn't contain any "}" character you won't even need any regex. the only thing you'd have to do is search for {for then search for } replace {for with <?for( and } with ):?> and you have the right replacement for the {for cond} part and then you just need to search for {/for} and replace it with <?endfor?> and it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick-and-dirty string literal string replacement:

```
$code = str_replace('{for ', '<?php for (', $code);
$code = str_replace(' }', '){ ?>', $code);
$code = str_replace('{/for}', '<?php } ?>', $code);
```

It will not work if `somethhingbetween` contains `if(){ }` because `}` gets replaced by `){ ?>`. But for other cases with just `{for condition }` and `{/for}`, it suffice.

Regular expression approach combined with simple string replacement, this assumes no occurences of `}` in the for loop (match everything except for `}`: `[^}]+`)

```
$code = preg_replace('/{for ([^}]+)}/', '<?php for ($1) { ?>', $code);
$code = str_replace('{/for}', '<?php } ?>', $code);
```

This function does no validating whatsoever, it's your responsibility to feed it with properly opened / closed `{for}` and `{/for}`s.

If you need to execute PHP, insert PHP. The other way would be writing your own parsing code. You could look at template projects like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

Comment: this replace all the } with {?> but i dont wanna do that.

Comment: @user658911: added regex approach. Note that `for` != `foreach`. So you'll have to use something like `{for $i=0; $i<2; $i++}...some code...{/for}`.

Comment: if you use the alternative php syntax then you could do the replacement like this: `{for` with `<?php for(` then replace all `{/for}` with `<?php endfor;?>` and in the end any remaining `}` with `):?>`